# Filter JSON string from String having json string and normal string in java

Tags: java, json

I am stuck in a problem where I have to filter json data from a String which is a combination of json string and normal text.

sample: `This message has all your required detail { "name" : "xyz","age": "21","place" :"sdf", "number": "7689"} check in this page you will get the details.`

I need to extract the json object from given string.

Result expected is only : `{ "name" : "xyz","age": "21","place" :"sdf", "number": "7689"}`.

Is there any clean way of doing this in Java.
One way to solve this is to remove non-json string and extract json object.
But that is a bad approach in my view.

Comment: Do you expect multiple json strings in a one java string?

Comment: No, There will be only one json string

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other JSON-like parts, you can just extract the part between the first `{` and last `}`, including both ends:

```
int start=str.indexOf('{');
int end=str.lastIndexOf('}');
String json=str.substring(start,end+1);
```

Then of course you may want to check if both `start` and `end` are non-negative (so the characters are actually present), if there is a possibility that the string does not contain anything for you.
Also note that JSON can be an array too, so you can try checking if a pair of first `[` and last `]` lies outside of the `{...}`, but then at the end single values are valid JSON too (like `true`, `false`, `1`, etc.). This is not really a happy task to write properly, thinking of everything.